# Как послать данные на ком-порт?

Tags: c#, com-порт

надо послать 0x55 на 3 ком-порт с одним стоп битом.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO.Ports;

    namespace Com
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3",
                                              2400,
                                              Parity.None,
                                              8,
                                              StopBits.One);
                    _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

                    _serialPort.Open();
                    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

                    byte sent = 0x55;
                    Console.WriteLine("sent: {0}", sent);
                    _serialPort.Write(new byte[1] { sent }, 0, 1);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception:, {0}", e);
                }
            }
            private static void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine("Data Received:, {0}", indata);          
                Console.ReadLine(); //Pause
            }
        }
    }
```

Вроде все верно. Но программа ничего не показывает. Где может закрасться ошибка?

Comment: А почему должна показывать? Посмотрите Portmon'ом на транзакции по этому порту

Comment: @tutankhamun или же можно замкнуть Rx и Tx.

Comment: чет не видит он ничего. хотя прога подцеплена к порту http://i.imgur.com/XeaihcI.jpg

Comment: Странно. Пишет, что не подключен. Вы порт выбрали в меню "Capture"?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Но это, например, не поможет увидеть проблемы с таймаутами. Я несколько лет назад наступил на грабли. Portmon тогда реально помог

Comment: @tutankhamun мы тоже ловили косяк в терминалке несколько недель... Но в данном случае, я думаю, все гораздо проще...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причин может быть много:

- возможно у вас в системе несколько СОМ-портов и вы отправляете не
  на тот;
- устройство которому вы отправляете посылку ничего не
  отвечает;
- скорость не подходит, попробуйте поставить, например,
  1200;
- попробуйте поменять таймауты.

  `_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
  _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;`

Или же ваша программа закрывается еще до получения ответа. Попробуйте так:

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3",
                                          2400,
                                          Parity.None,
                                          8,
                                          StopBits.One);
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

                _serialPort.Open();
                _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

                byte sent = 0x55;
                Console.WriteLine("sent: {0}", sent);
                _serialPort.Write(new byte[1] { sent }, 0, 1);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:, {0}", e);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Если у вас 1 СОМ-порт, то можно еще так записать `_serialPort.PortName = SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0];`

Comment: И еще вы точно уверены что на запрос 0х55 вам в ответ должно что-то прити? Обычно ни программы ни устройства не отвечают на  один байт информации. Любой протокол подразумевает еще всякую дополнительную информацию в посылке. Например в Modbus идет так: 1 байт - id устройства, 2 байт - номер функции, например 0х03, 3 и 4 байты - адрес начального регистра, 5 и 6 адрес - длина, которую необходимо считать и 7 и 8 байты - CRC.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша программа ничего не показывает потому что завершается. Поставьте в конец `Main` вызов `Console.ReadLine()`