# Как ловить данные из com-порта и использовать в своих программах?

Tags: arduino, com-порт

Возникла необходимость получать данные с Arduino, к ней подключен RC522 и в мониторе порта выводится 1 строка чисел, мне хочется чтобы при считывании эта строка 
1)выводилась на экран
2)записывалась в текстовик 
3)Отправлялась на сервер
Такое возможно?

Comment: Пишете программу, которая слушает COM-порт и принятые данные выводит на экран, в файл и шлет на сервер.

Comment: 1) Подойдет любой язык? 2) Быстрое ли будет чтение? 3) Любые данные которые пришли в монитор порта можно считать? То есть от любого датчика?

Comment: Любой язык, где вы сможете реализовать чтение порта. Быстрое будет чтение, если грамотно реализовать. Любые данные, что пришли в порт, можно читать. Он вообще в винде выглядит как файл.

Comment: Как файл? Впервые о таком слышу, можете поподробнее рассказать об этом? Стало интересно

Comment: Просто как файл. Открываете файл с именем COM1 и читаете-пишете в него.

Comment: Все равно не понял

Comment: Читайте документацию и примеры кода. Если я ничего не путаю, в MSDN тема ком-портов обмусолена со всех сторон.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два варианта либо искать в интернете программу, которая слушает СОМ-порт и как-то пересылать на сервер, либо писать программу самому. Во втором случае нужно определится с языком программирования.

Например, если вы решите использовать C#, то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456453/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82/456466#456466) есть фрагмент кода, который можно незначительно изменить и получить желаемый вами результат.

**Обновление**

чтение моментальное. Данные пришли данные отобразились. Можете изменять таймауты получения и отправки вручную (это миллисекунды). Программа видит все что пришло в ком порт, неважно  какой источник данных. Единственное что замечу в вашем случае возможно придется использовать не `ReadExisting`, a `ReadByte`. Зависит от формата передаваемых данных, нужно смотреть. Если будут вопросы создавайте новый вопрос, поможем.

Comment: 1) Быстрое ли будет чтение? 2) Любые данные которые пришли в монитор порта можно считать? То есть от любого датчика?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, вам окажется не бесполезной моя статья об этом. [Host-клиент Arduino на C (Linux)](http://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/host-klient-arduino-na-s-linux)